# Find out whether a value is present grouped by a value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks sort of like this:

```
CustomerID   ItemType
001          'a'
001          'b'
001          'c'
001          'd'
002          'd'
```

How can I structure a select statement that looks something like this:

```
CASE WHEN ItemType = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Aexists, 
CASE WHEN ItemType = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Bexists, 
CASE WHEN ItemType = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Cexists, 
CASE WHEN ItemType = 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Dexists,
CASE WHEN ItemType = 'e' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Eexists,
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Where the results would look like this:

```
CustomerID, Aexists, Bexists, Cexists, Dexists, Eexists
001         1        1        1        1        0 
002         0        0        0        1        0
```

I'm confused on how to tell if the items exist since they are spread over rows; I only want one row returned per customer.

Answer (score 1):

Close enough. Use aggregate function `MAX`

```
select
    CustomerID,
    max(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Aexists, 
    max(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Bexists, 
    max(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Cexists, 
    max(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'd' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Dexists,
    max(CASE WHEN ItemType = 'e' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Eexists
from t
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Clever. I was worried I'd have to do something silly like pivot. Thank you.